# При клике на кнопку добавить/удалить класс?

Tags: jquery

Как такое реализовать через Jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('active'); // добавляем или удаляем класс самой кнопке
   $('div').toggleClass('show'); // добавляем или удаляем класс нужному блоку
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ)